# How to prevent pandas dataframe from adding double quotes around #tmp when using sqlalchemy and sybase?

Tags: python, dataframe, sqlalchemy, sybase, temp-tables

I have reduced the issue to pandas to_sql adding double quotes around #tmp when dealing with sybase using sqlalchemy as the pooling framework.

> Code :

```
def get_data_with_tmp():
    engine = get_connection("sybase")
    with engine.connect() as conn:
        df = pd.DataFrame({'alias_id': ['345402KP5', '3454014R1']})
        df.to_sql(name='#tmp', con=conn, schema=None, if_exists='append', index=False)
        df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT alias_id from #tmp", con=conn)
```

> Error:

```
statement = '\nCREATE TABLE "#tmp" (\n\talias_id TEXT NULL\n)\n\n' E   pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [SAP][ASE ODBC Driver][Adaptive Server Enterprise]Incorrect syntax near '('.\n (102) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

When I remove the double quotes around #tmp it works fine in sybase.
Also, this same code works fine in SqlServer without any modifications.

Any idea how to solve this issue?
I would welcome alternative suggestions as well.
Note that I do have a workaround of looping through the dataframe and inserting row by row, but would really prefer a solution that makes use of dataframe good stuff like batching, batch insert etc.

Comment: I have reproduced your issue and have opened a ticket for the external dialect [here](https://github.com/gordthompson/sqlalchemy-sybase/issues/1).

Comment: hey, thanks for reproducing it and logging the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug has been fixed in the external sybase dialect

https://github.com/gordthompson/sqlalchemy-sybase

specifically

https://github.com/gordthompson/sqlalchemy-sybase/releases/tag/1.0.1

Comment: ok, i will mark your answer accepted, once I check it out - hopefully by friday - I had to move past this to commit some code to rely on it, but would definitely like to simplify the code to use to_sql

Comment: Gord - could you check - the sql statement currently being generated is this :"SELECT alias_id from '#tmp'", parameters = (). This also doesnt seem to be acceptable to sybase.

Comment: I tested `to_sql` and that worked, so I thought I was done. I'll try to reproduce the select.

Comment: ok, i was doing to_sql and for the sybase connection, that is the sql that is being thrown in the exception. It does look like you changed it from double quote, but probably further on downstream single quotes are being added. Neither single quotes nor double quotes are acceptable to sybase around the table name (unlike sqlserver). single quotes are needed for sqlite.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue with `read_sql_query`. [This code](https://pastebin.com/P6ryGtAW) works fine for me. Note that I am passing an `engine` object to `read_sql_query`.

Comment: ah, i will take a look. but the key difference is that I am passing a connection (engine.connect()) object. Reason is that the same connection has to be used to set up tmp table as the one to pull from it and I am using a connection pool. Is there a way to achieve that with the engine object?